# Photoshop Javascript solution for auto naming

Tags: javascript, image, automation, photoshop

I am a photo editor with constant high quantity turnaround. I've come up with a partial automation solution to my problem by creating an action that takes my image, and automates the process of duplicating it 4 times, automatically opening the cropping bounding box on them all, letting me crop the needed aspect ratios, and then automatically opening the save for web box on all the images (and then closing all except the original file. I still need to name each file individually though.

What I would like to add to that action is some type of script that automates further. I would like to get the initial save for web option, type in my file name, and then have a script to add the pixel dimensions to the end of that filename, and automatically use that filename and the pixel dimensions of the next 3 images saved automatically.

IE- my action runs. Save for web box comes up for image 1 of 4. I type in `"this_is_my_photo01_"`. Then the script would take that file name and save the four images with that and the dimensions of the photo (`this_is_my_photo01_800x450.jpg`, `this_is_my_photo01_600x400.jpg`, `this_is_my_photo01_800x800.jpg`, `this_is_my_photo01_800x125.jpg`)

Comment: Hi - this is a programming Q&A site - it helps to have a specific problem.  You've outlined some requirements for a tool - do you want help finding one off the shelf (which is not what this site is for), or do you want help writing one - in which case the code you've written so far would be helpful.

Comment: I'd say I'm wet behind the ears writing code, but it's probably more accurate to say I haven't even jumped in the water yet. I'm looking for help writing code. What I need is a bit beyond my grasp/comprehension.

Comment: I may be able to write you something... would it be ok to assume that you would only have your 4 images open in Photoshop (I mean "and no others")? Also, could I assume you would already have created any subdirectories into which you needed the images saving? And finally, are you running on a Mac or Windows? No promises - I have done a fair bit of this stuff before but don't know everything!

Comment: I have pretty much done what you are looking for - please answer my questions above if you are still interested...

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is (almost) completely scriptable, using Javascript, VBScript or Applescript (on Mac). This will allow MUCH more flexibility in generating names for images etc. than you will get with simple actions.

The Adobe guides are located [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/25/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/).